# OSError: [WinError 10057] Can't send anything through socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

Why is this resulting in an error?

```
import socket


HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 4444
ADDR = (HOST,PORT)
BUFSIZE = 4096

serv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

serv.bind(ADDR)
serv.listen(5)

while True:
  conn, addr = serv.accept()
  print ('client connected ... '), addr
  lol = "Hey".encode()
  serv.send(lol)
```

Client:

```
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 4444
ADDR = (HOST,PORT)
BUFSIZE = 4096

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)
while True:
orden = client.recv(4096).decode()
print(orden)
```

Error message is the following:

> OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was not
>   allowed because the socket is not connected and no address was
>   provided, when sending in a datagram socket by means of a sendto call.

Comment: The server needs to do all communications via the client socket returned by `.accept()`, not the original server socket.